# Testbox auto complete from string

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a notepad file of about 10,000 words. I can export them as csv or tab separated values as required. Is there a way for my words to appear as suggestions in a textbox (input type text)?

This word work in the same way as google.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you have the [datalist element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) which gives you a kind of autocomplete feature. Although I'm not really sure about what you want an answer to, for example it is probably not that efficient to put 10 000 words inside the datalist element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery along with some plugin for maximum cross-browsing capability.
Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
Click on the vew source link on the page to see how it is done.

**Edit:**
Since you are using a lot of elements, why not creating an ajax request after the text change to load the elements you want and then stream them into a div right under the text box? This will make you more in control of what the user is seing and it will work on all browsers.